# How can I prevent using SetPixel method?

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

I have class:

```
class MyPic  
{  
    private Bitmap bmp=null;

    public MyPic(Bitmap b)
    {
          bmp=b;
    }

    public Bitmap Bmp
    {
        get { return bmp; }
    }
}
```

I made Bmp readonly property but user still can modify it by using `SetPixel` method. How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not only call `SetPixel`, but also get a Graphics and draw on it. Bitmaps are mutable by design. If it is important to you that the user cannot modify your bitmap, create a copy using the copy constructor before returning it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts25csc8.aspx

Comment: Is `Bitmap ret = (Bitmap)bmp.Clone();` the same? I can return `ret` after that. Thanks:)